# How to check which external connections are being used by my website

Tags: url, google-maps-api-3

I'm not 100% sure if this is a programming question, but I do believe I'm targeting the correct audience for this issue.

I've built a web-based frontend for an application. Now the frontend will be deployed to the customer's machine (localhost-based website). However, this frontend uses Google Maps V3 and some other external components. It will need internet access, but the customer network is highly secured. Here my issues begin.

To make sure everything works as planned, we need to allow the connections that are being made when starting up the webpage, so I need a list of URLs that my frontend is using when starting up. I mainly need the google maps URLs, they are so varied (googleis.com, gstatic.com, ...)

How can I get a list of these URLs? Is there any Google documentation (didn't find any)?

I've thought about using Firebug and listing all entries in the Network tab. However, that scales to about 2000 items (including all images, scripts, CSS stylesheets etc that are being loaded from the local website).

Or is there a tool/workaround to easily find out which connections should be explicitly allowed for the website to work like it should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach of using the Firebug - Network tab is good. The Chrome Developer Tools - Network view is also very good. I haven't seen a list of everything that gets loaded by the map, but that is because it varies based on how you set up your map. I know that Google works hard to only load what is needed by your map, based on your options.

So if you only use selected map controls, Google will try to limit the image downloads to just what is needed to display the controls your map needs. Of course, if you include additional items, such as using a parameter on the URL that loads the drawing tools (`libraries=drawing`),  you will have additional network loading. Google defined these "extra" items as libraries to avoid loading everything; just those that need them will have to load them.

Other than setting your map up and watching what is loaded, I can't think of another option.